# Pause or stop numpy calculation after RuntimeWarning occured

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing some calculations using [`numpy.optimize.fsolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html). Due to inproper initial values some of those calculations lead to a RuntimeWarning telling

> RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured
>   by the    improvement from the last ten iterations.
>   warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)

or

> RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured
>   by the improvement from the last five Jacobian evaluations.
>   warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)

Since I am writing all initial values and the belonging results into a text-file (just piping stdout to a file), I want to get a clue in which calculation of my somewhat 500 steps the above mentioned RuntimeWarnings occured.

As mentioned in the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) the warnings are handled by [Python's standard warnings module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/warnings.html), but is there a way to stop or pause calculations after the first RuntimeWarning occured?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to terminate the calculation at the time a warning is issued, you can use the `warnings` module's ability to force certain types of warnings to be raised as exceptions. You can do this by writing:

```
warnings.simplefilter('error')
```

This will turn *all* warnings into errors and immediately halt the program. The downside is that the computation cannot be resumed by simply catching the exception: it's done for good.

If you wish to *pause* the program instead, you can use a little "hack" to override the function that the `warnings` module uses to display warnings. Overriding this function is explicitly allowed by the documentation, though our present purpose differs from what the docs have in mind. Here's a simple warning handler that asks the user whether or not to continue. If the user says no, the error is promoted to an exception:

```
def handle_warning(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    print('A warning occurred:')
    print(message)
    print('Do you wish to continue?')

    while True:
        response = input('y/n: ').lower()
        if response not in {'y', 'n'}:
            print('Not understood.')
        else:
            break

    if response == 'n':
        raise category(message)
```

And we then override the default warning handler:

```
warnings.showwarning = handle_warning
```

Now we try to optimize a flat function:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
fsolve(lambda x: 1, 1)
```

We almost immediately get a message:

```
A warning occurred:
The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
Do you wish to continue?
y/n:
```

If we answer `y`, the optimization will be allowed to continue and return its result. If we answer `n`, an exception is raised and the computation terminated.

### Context Manager Solution

Alternatively, if you don't want to override the `showwarning` function on the module level, you can use a context manager. We can place it inside a function that wraps everything up nice and neat:

```
def pause_if_warning(function, *args, **kwargs):
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.showwarning = handle_warning
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
```

So we can now write:

```
pause_if_warning(fsolve, lambda x: 1, 1)
```

to get the same behavior as above.

Comment: What input are you using to `fsolve`? I tested the above solution for an input of a constant function, and it appears to work.

Comment: It was just my own fault. - Simply don't pipe stdout to a file if using `input` for user interaction :-) Everything works like a charm, so I deleted my previous comment and ticked your answer solving my question.